# Titanium Android App Markeplace Build not starting

Tags: android, titanium

I made an Android app with Titanium Studio. It works perfecly as long as i run it in debug mode but as soon as i use the apk that's generated by the built in marketplace distribution my app gets stuck when the loading screen is shown. No error Message is displayed.

I created a keystore and verified the apk after it was built. no errors.

Any idea what i need to change?

DDMS:

```
11-13 21:57:26.142: I/ActivityManager(477): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.xxxx.xxxx/.xxxxActivity bnds=[360,74][536,302]} from pid 767
11-13 21:57:26.142: W/ContextImpl(477): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1078 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.SendToPermission:2575 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityUncheckedLocked:3177 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked:2788 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait:3343 
11-13 21:57:26.149: D/PowerManagerService(477): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=1112740064, flags=0x1, tag="ActivityManager-Launch", ws=null, uid=1000, pid=477
11-13 21:57:26.149: D/PowerManagerNotifier(477): onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="ActivityManager-Launch", ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=477, workSource=null
11-13 21:57:26.149: D/PowerManagerService(477): Update history[5] wakeLock: flags=0x1, tag="ActivityManager-Launch", uid=1000, pid=477, timeStamp=1384376246150, timeSum=8638
11-13 21:57:26.149: D/PowerManagerService(477): updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x1
11-13 21:57:26.149: D/PowerManagerService(477): updateScreenStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, newScreenState=2, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x1, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true
11-13 21:57:26.156: I/ComBroadcastReceiver(28917): ComBroadcastReceiver action = android.server.am.ActivityStack.taskstatechange
11-13 21:57:26.166: I/ActivityManager(477): Start proc com.xxxx.xxxx for activity com.xxxx.xxxx/.xxxxActivity: pid=10596 uid=10176 gids={50176, 1015, 3003, 1028}
11-13 21:57:26.179: I/dalvikvm(10596): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
11-13 21:57:26.202: D/Sensors(477): sensors_poll_context_t->activate(handle: 0, enabled: 1)
11-13 21:57:26.202: D/PowerManagerService(477): handleSandman: canDream=false, mWakefulness=Awake
11-13 21:57:26.206: D/Sensors(477): virtual int AccelerometerSensor::enable(int32_t, int): fd (230 ),en (1),flags(1), mEnabled(0),input_sys_path (/sys/class/input/event4/device/device/enable)
11-13 21:57:26.206: D/Sensors(477): sensors_poll_context_t->setDelay(handle: 0, ns: 200000000)
11-13 21:57:26.206: D/Sensors(477): sensors_poll_context_t->setDelay(handle: 0, ns: 66667000)
11-13 21:57:26.206: W/ActivityRecord(477): goujw packagename: com.xxxx.xxxx
11-13 21:57:26.209: W/ActivityRecord(477): goujw userId: 0
11-13 21:57:26.242: D/CubicBezierInterpolator(477): CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.5, mControlPoint1y = 0.2, mControlPoint2x = 0.6, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
11-13 21:57:26.249: W/System.err(10596): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-13 21:57:26.249: W/System.err(10596):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
11-13 21:57:26.252: I/PowerManagerService(477): state=2
11-13 21:57:26.252: W/System.err(10596):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109)
11-13 21:57:26.252: W/System.err(10596):    at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.readDefaultConfig(ResourcesEx.java:808)
11-13 21:57:26.252: W/System.err(10596):    at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.<init>(ResourcesEx.java:741)
11-13 21:57:26.252: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1721)
11-13 21:57:26.252: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1752)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:485)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1911)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1904)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4269)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:145)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 21:57:26.256: W/System.err(10596): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-13 21:57:26.259: W/System.err(10596):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-13 21:57:26.259: W/System.err(10596):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-13 21:57:26.259: W/System.err(10596):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
11-13 21:57:26.259: W/System.err(10596):    ... 19 more
11-13 21:57:26.272: I/TiApplication(10596): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
11-13 21:57:26.356: W/System.err(10596): Invalid int: ""
11-13 21:57:26.416: I/TiApplication(10596): (main) [141,141] Titanium 3.1.3 (2013/09/18 12:01 222f4d1)
11-13 21:57:26.482: I/TiApplication(10596): (main) [68,209] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
11-13 21:57:26.482: D/dalvikvm(10596): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.xxxx.xxxx-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x424249f0
11-13 21:57:26.486: D/dalvikvm(10596): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.xxxx.xxxx-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x424249f0
11-13 21:57:26.486: D/dalvikvm(10596): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.xxxx.xxxx-2/libstlport_shared.so 0x424249f0, skipping init
11-13 21:57:26.486: D/dalvikvm(10596): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.xxxx.xxxx-2/libkroll-v8.so 0x424249f0
11-13 21:57:26.496: D/dalvikvm(10596): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.xxxx.xxxx-2/libkroll-v8.so 0x424249f0
11-13 21:57:26.502: I/TiRootActivity(10596): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
11-13 21:57:26.502: I/TiApplication(10596): (main) [1,1] Analytics have been disabled
11-13 21:57:26.706: W/V8Object(10596): Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
```

Comment: If you are using Alloy look for `if (ENV_DEV)` and `if (ENV_PRODUCTION)`. When used improperly they could trigger such weird behaviour of app.

Comment: i dont use alloy but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: I faced with same issue on Huawei. @NilsWild Do you have any updated on this

Comment: No it seems that its an error with the huawei permission manager. it works like charm on my samsung tablet